# Criar botão de compartilhar no Linkedin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, api

Estou desenvolvendo um Projeto Web e neste projeto contém o botão para compartilhar no Linkedin (personalizado).

Já trabalhei com compartilhar do Facebook e Twitter e até o momento está funcionando normal, porém nunca utilizei o compartilhamento do Linkedin, alguém já utilizou e pode me ajudar?

Segue código:

Compartilhar do Facebook:

Html:

```
<a href="" ng-click="vm.facebook(baseurl + 'conteudo/' + conteudo.slug)">
    <div class="img-circle compartilhar_icones">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</a>
```

JS:

```
vm.facebook = function (s) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + s, '/&display=popup&ref=plugin', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=770, HEIGHT=200');
    };
```

Este código acima está funcionando, segue o código que estou utilizando para o Linkedin, porém não está em funcionamento:

Html:

```
<a href="" ng-click="vm.linkedin(baseurl + 'conteudo/' + conteudo.slug, conteudo.nome)">          
  <div class="img-circle compartilhar_icones terceiro">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin icone_linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</a>
```

JS:

```
vm.linkedin = function (s, a){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=' + s +';title=' + a +'', '', '550', '510', 'yes');
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente como está a usar angular deve mudar alguma coisa, no entanto um dos erros que me deu foi:

> ...event not defined...

Mas em angular isto pode não acontecer.

Não sei se vai ajudar, mas aqui está da maneira 'nativa':

```
<a href="#" onclick="linkedin(event, 'yo.com', 'meu nome');return false;">          
  <div class="img-circle compartilhar_icones terceiro">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin icone_linkedin" aria-hidden="true">LINKDIN</i>
   </div>
</a>
```

JS:

```
linkedin = function (event, s, a){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=' +s+ '?name=' +a, 'newwindow', 'width=680, height=450');
};
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/7yngdovr/) funcional no jsfiddle

Comment: Ele já positivou e marcou como resposta certa, mas, não seria melhor em API esse compartilhamento??

Comment: Eu apresentei o que sabia, mas de qualquer maneira se for só para fazer share não é preciso, note que isto só acontece porque o linkedin/facebook assim o querem/autorizam: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/.
@WilliamAparecidoBrandino veja aqui um exemplo tirado daí: https://jsfiddle.net/7yngdovr/1/ . Como vê para isto (share) não tem de passar disto