# Botão para compartilhar no LikedIn

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando compartilhar noticias do meu site no LikedIn, só que não estou conseguindo compartilhar.

Tentei seguir este tópico [Criar botão de compartilhar no Linkedin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145704/criar-bot%C3%A3o-de-compartilhar-no-linkedin) só que não funcionou pra mim.

Meu código:

```
<a href="#" onclick="linkedin(event, '<?= Site ?>/noticias/?noticia=2', '<?= $noticia->title ?>');return false;">
    <button type="button" class="btn info";"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></button>
</a>

linkedin = function (event, s, a){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=' +s+ '?name=' +a, 'newwindow', 'width=680, height=450');
};
```

Ele não está mandando o `id` da notícia para o compartilhamento.

Comment: Não seria `<?=$Site ?>`?

Comment: É só uma variável do sistema